# Any elegant way to remove flicker for dockable controls?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, docking

I want to add docking capabilities in an application, haven't had a need for that, now I do, but whenever clicking and dragging a panel towards or from a "docksite", the window rectangle is painted ugly(flickering) on the desktop canvas.

So, my question is:

- any simple and elegant way to overcome this by overriding some method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a brilliant Sample Project available on the [Official RAD Studio Demos SVN Repository](https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/Delphi/VCL/Docking). This demo does *everything* you're trying to do with regards to tidy docking without flickering. It perfectly recreates the way Windows can be docked in the RAD Studio IDE itself.

Answer (score 2):

I do a **lot** of docked UIs, and the only way I've found thus far is by using a third-party docking solution such as found in the JVCL.

If you drop a `TJvDockServer` on your main form (the one into which other forms will be docked), then drop a `TJvDockClient` onto each of the aforementioned docked forms, assign both the same Style (such as `TJvDockVCStyle`), it totally changes the behaviour of docking, including the rendered rect when dragging the windows to dock.

Perhaps you could pull from these components the desired code to draw your own custom rect to represent the forms when dragging to dock.

Comment: +1 thank you, but I want to keep third party components at minimum, looking to overcome this issue...

Comment: Understandable, hence the suggestion to perhaps take a look at how they're doing it, and adapt to your own needs (I'll be doing the same with my `TDockPanel` control, since I'm now updating it with additional supporting controls such as `TDockPageControl`)

Comment: I guess there's no elegant way to overcome this issue without using some third party controls, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It is one of the annoyances persisting to this day in Delphi. Still, there's nothing stopping you from implementing your own solution to avoid the use of third-party components/packages ;)

Answer (score 0):

The emba code sample has moved:
svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/branches/RadStudio_XE/Delphi/VCL/Docking